# Viewing what interfaces a class implements in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I feel like the answer will be a "oh, THAT button, duh" sort of thing for me, but I can't figure out a quick way to do what I want, so here goes.

I've read the best practices around always wrapping "using" statements around objects that implement IDisposable to clean them up properly, but that got me thinking: "well, how do I *know* it implements IDisposable?" Let's take System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, for example. I can eventually figure out that it implements IDisposable by viewing the class in the object browser, then jumping to its base (System.Data.Common.DbConnection), and then expanding "Base Types" for that class.

That seems like a roundabout way to figure out if a certain interface is implemented; any quicker ways? I use Visual Studio 2008 and have ReSharper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With resharper you can just use the **<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>** command (Go to base symbols) on an item and that can drill you down to the base classes in a jiffy. Also consider **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>** to **Go to type of symbol**

Comment: Nice! One more keyboard shortcut to add to my ReSharper ninja skills :) Thanks!